# How do I get the size and last modification date of a directory?

Tags: disk-usage

I have been recently using Unix/Linux systems.
I need to get the space details and the last date modified for a directory and it's subdirectories.

I have tried using this command to get the Filesize in GB:

```
du -h /myfolder/ | grep '[0-9\.]\+G
```

I need to get the last date on which it was modified.

Comment: Are you trying to get the modification time of every directory, or just the most recent time for all of the subdirectories?

Comment: Hi Eric, I am trying to get the last modified dates along with sizes in GB/TB for each Directory and it's Sub Directory

Comment: That didn't answer @EricRenouf's question, if you have `/foo/bar/`, and you create `/foo/bar/file`, should that update the last modified time of `bar`, of `foo` and `bar`, or should it should `/foo/bar` remain with the same last modified time as before the operation?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the last modified time and total size of each directory you could do something like

```
find /root_directory_of_search -type d -printf '%c %p\n' -exec du -sh {} \;
```

to print the last change time followed by the path to the directory and then the total space used by that directory and everything in it.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by using the option `--time` with du.

```
du -h --time /myfolder/ ... (other options)
```